# How do you set a vlan priority on a nic in freeBSD?

Tags: networking, freebsd, vlan

This question could arguably be posted on both networking.stackexchange and unix.stackexchange. I'll start here.

I have a freeBSD ([pfsense 2.1](http://www.pfsense.org)) server running as a router on google fiber.

In order to get above 10 Mbps I need to enable egress filtering on the wan port
(aka 802.1p, traffic priority, Class of Service, CoS, vlan pcp ).

Running ifconfig, I can see that the `vlanpcp` is set to 0.

How do I change the `vlanpcp` from 0 to 3 ?

```
ifconfig
...
re0_vlan2: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1500
    options=3<RXCSUM,TXCSUM>
    ether 00:1c:c0:d5:e0:e2
    inet 23.255.241.45 netmask 0xfffff800 broadcast 23.255.247.255
    inet6 fe80::21c:c0ff:fed5:e0e2%re0_vlan2 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x8
    nd6 options=3<PERFORMNUD,ACCEPT_RTADV>
    media: Ethernet autoselect (1000baseT <full-duplex>)
    status: active
    vlan: 2 vlanpcp: 0 parent interface: re0
```

It looks link on linux [this can be done with](http://etutorials.org/Networking/Integrated+cisco+and+unix+network+architectures/Chapter+13.+Policy+Routing+Bandwidth+Management+and+QoS/802.1PQ+TaggingPriority-QoS+at+the+Data-LinkMAC+Sublayer/) `vconfig`, however freebsd doesn't use vconfig.

For reference, I am using these instructions for setting up the vlans.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/zg9ju9373t0fnpu/GoogleFiberRouterGuide.pdf

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/fiber/AbNh8ij72Mw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FreeBSD is not like Linux. This is particularly true regarding network configuration: "everything" is in `ifconfig`. A simple `man ifconfig` will confirm you that.

So to change the value of `vlanpcp` for you **re0_vlan2**:

```
ifconfig re0_vlan2 vlanpcp 3
```

More to read:

- [ifconfig manual](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?ifconfig%288%29)
- [vlan mini-HowTo](http://people.freebsd.org/~arved/vlan/vlan_en.html)  (slightly out-dated)